# Storing web analytics data

Tags: mysql, csv, analytics, storing-data

On my website I have a video page like youtube, I want to store data when a user visits the video page. The data I want to store is **videoID**, **IP**, **referrer** and **date**.

My concern is that I am not sure of the best way to store this data. One option I have thought about is MySQL and the other is in a CSV file. If I have lots of data which option would be the quickest to read the data from?

I can think about pros and cons for both options but what is your opinion? (Keeping in mind growth of the website). Also, are there any other viable options I have not thought about?

*Note: I have thought about google analytics but this is not an option.*

Comment: Is there a reason against simply using external analytics services, such as Google's?

Comment: I have thought about using google analytics then using google api to pull the data but there are limits to the number of queries. I also need this data for other users of my website to see.

Comment: Piwik is open source and you could host it yourself. No limits there and displaying the results via Piwik's API is entirely feasible (ie, I've done it in the past).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySQL with the ARCHIVE storage engine. This will prove very time- and space- efficient for writing tonnage of log records, and will prove reasonably efficient for sequentially accessing the data for summarizing.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html

It's unsuitable for random access to the stored data. That kind of access will work,  but will be absurdly slow.

But, think twice about re-inventing the flat tire. Google Analytics works very well indeed.

Comment: Thank you, I have just briefly read up on ARCHIVE storage engine, and this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.